# Visual Studio Build doesn't start in one time click or F5 press

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

At first time click `build` or `press F5`, build process in not started, it shows the `'|'` blink in `Output window` and nothing happened. Then only if i cancel the build process and again start the `build` then it start building the project. Sometimes i should try several times build and cancel process to start the real build process.

I'm using
`Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.8.8` and `.net Framework version 4.7.0.3056` having issue in  `HP Laptop 15-bs0xx`

Comment: Have you tried some troubleshootings? Like, (1) update your Visual Studio to the latest version, (2) create a new blank solution to test, (3) repair your Visual Studio, (4) Restart VS or PC, (5) Reinstall Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, It was Bugs in  `VS2017 v15.8` and Fixed in New Release `VS2017 v15.9` and they categories this issue as `Major` with `tag`

> Build does not start if XAML files are not manually saved first.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes